# Display data in new window from GridView certain row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Currently I have a GridView that has a column with a date. This column has a link in each cell that opens up a window and displays an aspx page. *What I want it to do is to have the link open a window and display the date for that certain row and other information in a new GridView.*

Here is my code:

ascx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="summary1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" EmptyDataText="No Records Found..." >
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow"/>
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="ui-state-default" />
        <Columns>            
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
                <ItemTemplate> <%--edited the javascript--%> 
                    <a href="javascript:showDateProfile('%# Eval('DateFormat') %')" id="link1" runat="server" class="underline"><%# Eval("DateFormat") %></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Orders" HeaderText="Orders" SortExpression="Orders" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cancels" HeaderText="Cancels" SortExpression="Cancels" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Net" HeaderText="Net" SortExpression="Net" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

javascript (in aspx file) - edited

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDateProfile(x) {
    var w1 = window.open("DateProfile.aspx?id=x", "Profile", "width=800,height=600");
}

// edit
var qs = this.Request.QueryString["x"];
</script>
```

I would greatly appreciate help on how to get it to work how I want. Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT**

Is this a good way to do the data source for the gridview in the new window?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
SelectCommand="SELECT uid, name, company, startdate, enddate FROM Customer WHERE (startdate = @Date) or (enddate = @Date)" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:New_QuickBooksConnectionString %>">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="Date" QueryStringField="DateFormat" Type="Object" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: you can pass, your unique key (id) as `Query String` like `window.open("DateProfile.aspx?id=1", "Profile", "width=800,height=600");` and in `DateProfile` page, get a query by this `Query String` against your `DB` and fetch all you need, and bind to new `GridView`, and to pass `id` to `showDateProfile()` i think you can do this, `href="javascript:showDateProfile('%# Eval("DateFormat") %')`

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick reply! I'm not sure how to bind to the gridview like you were saying.

Comment: i post an answer, if its not clear let me know to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrote a sample for you, which shows all `persons` and by click on `BirthDate` column, user is redirected to another page,
this is main page code front (WebForm1.aspx) :

```
<script>

    function showDateProfile(x) {

        window.open("DateProfile_1.aspx?id=" + x, "Profile", "width=800,height=600");
    };

</script>

<asp:GridView ID="PersonGridView_Master" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>            
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BirthDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="javascript:showDateProfile('<%#Eval("id")%>')"><%# Eval("date")%></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

i have no DataSource control because i bound data from code behind (WebForm1.aspx.cs), details doesn`t matter

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }

    public void BindGrid()
    {
        // you can bind data to your grid in different ways
        // SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource, ... , it doesn`t matter

        PersonGridView_Master.DataSource = GetPersons();
        PersonGridView_Master.DataBind();
    }

    public object GetPersons()
    {
        // you can fetch your data in different ways, it doesn`t matter

        TestEntities context = new TestEntities();
        return context.tbl_Persons
            .Select(u => new
            {
                id = u.fldID,
                name = u.fldFirstName,
                date = u.fldBirthDate
            })
            .ToList();
    }
```

now, in second page...
this is my second page code front (DateProfile_1.aspx),

```
<asp:GridView ID="PersonGridView_Detail" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>            
            <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="BirthDate"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and also here, i dont have any data source control, because i bound data from code behind...
this is code behind of (DateProfile_1.aspx.cs)

```
public partial class DateProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get from query string and casting to its type
        Guid id = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);

        // populate grid
        BindGridToPerson(id);
    }

    public void BindGridToPerson(Guid ID)
    {
        // you can bind data to your grid in different ways
        // if you can use SqlDataSource, ObjectDataSource, you need to set property on those
        // to say that they need to get id from query string, in this way, we bind data
        // to grid manually

        PersonGridView_Detail.DataSource = GetPersonByID(ID);
        PersonGridView_Detail.DataBind();
    }

    public object GetPersonByID(Guid ID)
    {
        // you can fetch your data in different ways, it doesn`t matter

        TestEntities context = new TestEntities();
        return context.tbl_Persons
            .Select(u => new
            {
                id = u.fldID,
                name = u.fldFirstName,
                date = u.fldBirthDate
            })
            .Where(u => u.id == ID)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

and i have another page use `SqlDataSource` to Bind data, in this case, you dont need any server side code, for this reson, i post just code front (DateProfile_2.aspx):

```
   <asp:GridView ID="PersonGridView_Detail" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>            
            <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="BirthDate"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Web_TestConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [fldID], [fldBirthDate] as date, [fldFirstName] as name 
            FROM [Common].[tbl_Persons] 
            where [fldID] = @id">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="id" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and the end, let me know, if this post was usefull to you

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! I get this error: `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'id'.` It shows the error is here: `<a href="javascript:showDateProfile('<%#Eval("id")%>')"><%# Eval("DateFormat")%></a>`

Comment: have you replaced my code exactly? you need to do some customization, you have to use your own field name instead, in my project i had a field name by `id` name, in your project, you have to use the unique key field name, if the posts are useful to you, vote them, iv they are your answer, check them as answer, to help others when they read posts

Answer (score 0):

first you need to pass your unique identifier to `showDateProfile()` to pas to second page, for this, probably yo can define `<a>` element in markup like this

`<a href="javascript:showDateProfile('<%# Eval("YOUR_UNIQUE_INDETIFIER_FIELD_NAME") %>')" id="link1" runat="server" class="underline"><%# Eval("DateFormat") %></a>`

then you need to pass id from `showDateProfile()` to second page as `Query String` like this:

`function showDateProfile(id) {
    var w1 = window.open("DateProfile.aspx?x="id, "Profile", "width=800,height=600");
}`

then in second page_load event, you can get unique identifier has been passed like this:

`this.Request.QueryString["x"]`

and cast to its type, for example, if your id is type of `Guid`, you need to do this: `Guid.Parse(this.Request.QueryString["x"])`

and then, you have id, and the only thing is to get inforamtion from your DB and show them with any thing, like `GridView`

Comment: Can you look at my edited post, please? I added things according to your answer but I don't know if I did it right.

Comment: change `href="javascript:showDateProfile('%# Eval('DateFormat') %')"`(your markup) to `href="javascript:showDateProfile('%# Eval("YOUR_UNIQUE_INDETIFIER_FIELD_NAME") %'`(what i mean) and edit your javascript method(`x` must be out of string, because its a variable) like this `window.open("DateProfile.aspx?id=" + x, "Profile", "width=800,height=600");`

Comment: and this line causing exception in javascript `var qs = this.Request.QueryString["x"];` you should do this, at `DateProfile` code behind in `DateProfile.cs` on page_load, this is not `javascript`, and because  you pass query string like this `"DateProfile.aspx?id=" + x` you need to refer query string by `"id"` like this `this.Request.QueryString["id"];`